# Multivariate Analysis with Missing Values and Binary Data

Tags: multivariate-analysis, missing-data, binary-data

I am trying to run multivariate analysis on a fairly large data set and I'm looking for some help with deciding what type of statistical tools would be best suited for my project. I have a data set in which I have 5 independent variables and a waveform that is the dependent variable and the output of each experiment.

Regarding my independent variables, I have 3 experimental variables that I controlled as well as 2 more that relate to time (i.e. what day was the experiment was conducted -- to test for fatigue/adaptation). The 3 experimental variables include 1 that is continuous and 2 that are categorical.

Several of my professors have recommended that I look into MANOVA. According to their suggestion, I've started breaking down the waveform into the components of interest -- stuff like "response time to stimulus", "response amplitude to stimulus", and "number of peaks after stimulus". Continuing along these lines, I've defined 4 continuous waveform properties that I was thinking that I could use as dependent variables.

One issue I've run into is that these waveform properties will involve several missing values. For example, if there was no response to stimulus, then I don't have a response time or amplitude. Additionally, I was thinking of including a binary dependent variable to answer "was there a response to stimulus" that is based whether or not a peak was detected within some window of time after stimulus. Do you guys have any suggestions for how to handle these issues?

Do you all feel that MANOVA is indeed the best way to go about this?

Comment: See what Rubin and Little say about missing data in their classic book.